# Method can be overridden, but doesn't have to be

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I understand that `@abstractmethod`s use in an `ABC` is to dictate that a method must be implemented in the concrete implementation of the `ABC`.

What if I have a class with methods that *can* be overridden, but don't have to be? What's the best way to let users know that the method must be overridden to provide functionality?

Situation where base method *is* overridden:

```
import warnings

class BaseClass(object):
    def foo(self):
        """This method can do things, but doesn't."""

        warnings.warn('This method must be overridden to do anything.')

class ConcreteClass(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
        """This method definitely does things."""

        # very complex operation
        bar = 5

        return bar
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = ConcreteClass()
>>> a.foo()
5
```

Situation where base method *is not* overridden:

```
import warnings

class BaseClass(object):
    def foo(self):
        """This method can do things, but doesn't."""

        warnings.warn('This method must be overridden to do anything.')

class ConcreteClass(BaseClass):
    def other_method(self):
        """Completely different method."""

        # code here

    def yet_another_method(self):
        """One more different method."""

        # code here
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = ConcreteClass()
>>> a.foo()
__main__:1: UserWarning: This method must be overridden to do anything.
```

The reason I want to have the base method do anything *at all* is mainly due to user-friendliness. Colleagues within my group that have less experience using software could benefit from a kick in the rear reminding them that the script they wrote with my package isn't broken, they just forgot to add something.

Comment: *can be overridden, but don't have to be?* - This is the opposite you show in your code. [Edit] your Question and show another example.

Comment: If I want the method definition (for IDE support, maybe) but don't want to provide a default implementation I just `return NotImplemented` -- not sure there's a "standard" for this, however.

Comment: @jedwards: `return NotImplemented` is for when an operator overload doesn't understand how to handle its argument. For a method that straight-up doesn't have an implementation, `raise NotImplementedError` is more appropriate.

Comment: All methods *can* be overridden; Python doesn't have a notion of "final" methods. You don't have to do anything special to mark a method as optionally overridable, as that is assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method in python *already* can be overridden but doesn't have to be.
So for the rest of the question:

> What's the best way to let users know that the method **must** be
>   overridden to provide functionality?

You can raise a `NotImplementedError`:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class ConcreteClass(BaseClass):
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

And regarding

> a kick in the rear reminding them that the script they wrote with my
>   package isn't broken, they just forgot to add something.

An exception is much more explicit and helpful than a warning (that could easily be missed when thousands of log records had printed)

Comment: I considered this, but the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError) leave me confused as to whether this is a poor usage of that exception, as my class is not *required* to override the method.

Comment: I would recommend to implement what you can on base and let the derived methods to complete the work, OR, that derived class do all the work and base is abstract. But you want something else. You want to help other programmers because reasons :) [python is for adults](https://python-guide-chinese.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/writing/style.html#we-are-all-consenting-adults) that's probably why the docs left you confused, what you are asking is not "pythonic".

Comment: This is the best way to do it - your class isn't required to override that method, it only raises the exception if you try to use it and it hasn't been implemented.

Comment: @questionable_code I'm still confused about  what your trying to accomplish. You're saying "my class is not required to override this method." So will you be implementing the ConcreteClass, or is it your colleagues? If it is the latter then the docs you referred to seem (IMHO) to indicate that the proposed solution would be perfectly fine. It's not appropriate in the case where for some reason a method should never be implemented at all, indicating a programming error from someone using the concrete class.

Comment: @Alain The actual architecture of what I'm developing can end up having any number of concrete implementations. The idea is that my base class has the attributes and behaviors common among all use cases. Some of the methods, e.g. `foo` *might* be necessary in certain base implementations, but could also not be. It's still necessary to have it in the base class IMO because of the nature of the problem space. If someone writes a concrete implementation of the base class **not** including `foo`, then tries to use `foo`, I want them to know exactly what happened.